# Firebase security - how to stop overwriting

Tags: json, firebase, firebase-security, firebase-realtime-database

here is my datastructure:

```
{
   "items" : {
      "item0" : {
         "uniqueID" : 5,
         "uniqueID" : 31,
         "uniqueID" : 88
      },
      "item1" : {
         "uniqueID" : 22,
         "uniqueID" : 3
      }
   }
}
```

I would like for the user to be able to:

1-create a new item

2-create a new uniqueID (entry in an item)

I would like to stop the user from:

3-deleting anything

4-creating anything other than mentioned above

here is my incorrect attempt:

```
{
    "rules": {
        ".read": true,
        ".write": false,
        "items": {
          ".write": "!data.exists()"
        }
    }
}
```

I believe the `".write": false` should accomplish task 3 and 4, and that `".write": "!data.exists()"` should accomplish task 1 and 2, but this solution stops any data from being written to the db

Write operations that should fail:

```
var killItem0 = {};
killItem0['item0'] = 'all item 0 entries are now replaced by this text';
REF.child('items/').update(killItem0); //this replaces all data held by item0
```

Comment: Can you show some write operations that succeed, but should be prevented?

Comment: updated!, look at the original question

Comment: Your current write rule is for the entire items node, so if any data already exist you can't do anything right now. What you want is to go deeper and have rules for the unique id's.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think something like this should work:

```
{
"rules": {
  ".read": true,
  "items": {
      "$itemID": {
          "$uniqueID": {
             //check if data is already there and new data in a number (going off your example data for the number part)
             ".write": "!data.exists() && newData.isNumber()"
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I think you may have one level too many now. It's just `/items/$itemid` isn't it?

Comment: hey, nice answer! I found it to be almost correct, I needed to add ".write":"!data.exists()" as the second entry in "$itemID" to allow for new item# to be added.